# Draw border around controls on VBA Userform without using a Frame?

Tags: vba, userform

I am designing a VBA UserForm (in Excel, if it is relevant) and I would like some controls to be visually grouped together.. but when I put them in a frame, I am getting some undesired results (part of it has to do with the RefEdit control which seems to be particularly unhappy inside a frame).

Is there a way to draw a border around a group of controls on a form without putting them inside a Frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a label with the caption deleted and the border style set to `fmBorderStyleSingle`. It may appear on top of your other controls, so right click on it and select "send backwards" until it's behind your other controls.

Comment: I tried this, and it puts the label "on top of" the controls. How can I put it behind them? (I don't see any property like "zorder" that I can change)

Comment: @Josh Right click - "Send Backward".

Comment: OK, it seems like I have to click "Send Backward" a whole bunch of times but it eventually went behind all of my controls. Thank you.

Comment: In the format menu, there's an option to send to back.  Format, Order, Send to back.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create the shape over where you need it to be.  Drag highlight everything that you want on top of it, then right click and brink it all forwards.  Then when you drag your shape back over the top it will in fact be underneath everthing else.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and I was at first having the same issue where I had to choose to "Send Backward" up to 30 times per label in some cases. I found that hitting the Ctrl-K sends it to the back of all controls with one time hitting these keys.

Comment: Thanks, do you know you're answering a question that's almost 10 years old? Pretty sure I solved it with the accepted answer, but I obviously have moved on from that problem...